# Google earth historical imagery date

Tags: remote-sensing

I am working on a small creek in Colorado using historical imagery via Google earth. I want to know if the imagery date at the bottom of each image on google earth is the date the google acquired the image. Or, is it the date the satellite recorded it?

I came across this blog post online (https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-find-out-the-date-of-satellite-images-used-in-Google-Maps), which suggests that the two dates do not always match.

Does google provide metadata for imagery? Please advice.

Comment: You might look at earthexplorer.usgs.gov to see if you can find the original imagery and thus date.

Comment: Could you provide in more detail what are you going to use with it when you download it ? What software ?

Comment: You can try [ESRI Imagery Wayback](https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/wayback) it has images from 2014-present.